# Lebesgue measure of region under curve

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, product-measure

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finte measure space and $f \in L^+(X,\Sigma)$. Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

> Theorem:
>
> Define the area under the graph of $f$ to be $S_f = \{(x,y) \in X \times [0,\infty]\mid y \leq f(x)\}$. Then $S_f \in \Sigma \otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Moreover, $\mu \times \lambda(S_f) = \int f\,d\mu$

My proof:
$(x,y) \to f(x) - y$ is the composition of
            $\psi(x,y) = (f(x),y)$ and the subtraction $\phi(z,y) = z-y:
   [0,\infty] \times [0,\infty[ \to
   [-\infty,\infty[$. The former is
            automatically measurable since $f \in L^+(X)$, and
            $$ \phi^{-1}(z,y) = z + (-1)y
   $$
            is the composite of measurable functions, and is measurable.
            Therefore $S_f = (\psi \circ \phi)^{-1}
   [0,\infty[ \cup (f^{-1}[\{\infty\}]
   \times \infty) \in \Sigma\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$.

For the second part, extend $\lambda$ to $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ by setting $\lambda\{\infty\} = 0$. By Tonelli's Theorem,
$$\begin{align*} \mu \times \lambda(S_f)
&= \int_{X \times [0,\infty]}\chi_{S_f}\,d\mu\times\lambda \\
&= \int_X \int_{[0,\infty]} [y \leq f(x)]\,d\lambda(y)\,d\mu(x) \\
&= \int_X f(x) \,d\mu(x)
\end{align*}$$
Is my proof correct?

Comment: It is, except the part that I replied to in the question that you erased.

Comment: @Jonas I felt that the question was too trivial to be asked

Comment: I understand. :-) But my answer is as it should be: you need only to be careful with infinity.

Comment: @Jonas Is infinity necessary? It still keeps the $\sigma$-finiteness of $\lambda$, which is the only property I need to use Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: $f$ is integrable by hypothesis.